# If $f(z)$ is a 1-to-1 analytic function on the unit disk and $f(0)=0$, show that there is an analytic function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)^2 = f(z^2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

This is a question from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam that I'm trying to work through in order to study for my own upcoming qual. I'm not sure where to start with this one, to be honest.

**Problem:**

If $f(z)$ is a one-to-one analytic function on the unit disk and $f(0)=0$, show that there is an analytic function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)^2 = f(z^2)$ on the unit disk.

**Current progress:**

The only place I can think to start is with the definition of a one-to-one function, which is both

*Injective*: If $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, then $z_1 = z_2$.

*Surjective*: If $z_2 \in \mathbb{D}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk, then there exists a $z_1 \in \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(z_1) = z_2$.

Also, if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ has no other zeros and there is no other fixed point such that $f(z_1) = z_1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say $f$ is a function on the unit disk, do you mean that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $|z| \leq 1$?

Comment: Btw this is a sore spot for me because I had this question on a final and whiffed it. I'll let you know if I think of anything.

Comment: You could try separating $f$ and $g$ into the form $u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, then show that if $f$ satisfies cauchy-riemann, then so does $g$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I'm not certain whether the question means the open or closed disk. The question simply states "on the unit disk". Thankfully, it seems like the answer given below doesn't need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I like this idea, but I think the hard part is going to be showing that $g$ is single-valued. I think there's not going to be any way around using a pretty strong result about anti-derivatives, integrals of analytic functions, etc.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yeah, it ends up proving something related but different: for any holomorphic function $f$, if $g(x,y)$'s partial derivatives exist and $g(x,y)^2 = f(x+i y)$, then $g(Re[z],Im[z])$ is a holomorphic function. It's part of the way to the answer to this problem, but you still of course must show that $g(x,y)$'s partials exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is not identically $0$ it has a zero of some finite order at $0$. So we can write $f(z)=z^{N} F(z)$ where $F$ is analytic and  has no zeros in the unit disk. [$F(z)=z^{-N}f(z) \neq 0$ for $0<|z|<1$ since $f$ has no zeros other than $z=0$].

Now $f(z^{2})=z^{2N} F(z^{2})$. Since the unit disk is simply connected any analytic fucniton on it with no zeros has  an anayltic square root. So $F(z^{2})=(h(z))^{2}$  for some analytic function $h$. It follows that $f(z^{2})= [z^{N}h(z)]^{2}$.

Comment: Is there a short proof that $h$ exists? Is it just that composition of analytic functions is analytic?

Comment: No, existence of logarithms (and hence also square roots) of anlytic functions is not trivial. @CharlesHudgins

Comment: Is it the construction where you take $\int_\gamma \frac{f'}{f}$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yes, that is right. You need indepndence of paths to show that if $\gamma$ is the path from a fixed point $z_0$ to a variable point $z$ in your integral then you get an analytic function $h$ wiht $h'=\frac {f'} f$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. That was very clear. Learning to come up with these proofs is a real challenge for me.